# All files in one dir, linux

Tags: linux, bash

Today I tried a script in linux to get all files in one dir. It was pretty straightforward, but I found something interesting.

```
 #!/bin/bash
InputDir=/home/XXX/
for file in $InputDir'*'
do
  echo $file
done
```

The output is:

```
/home/XXX/fileA /home/XXX/fileB
```

But when I just input the dir directly, like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
InputDir=/home/XXX/
for file in /home/XXX/*
do
  echo $file
done
```

The output is:

```
/home/XXX/fileA
/home/XXX/fileB
```

It seems, in the first script, there was only one loop and all the file names were stored in the variable $file in the FIRST loop, separated by space. But in the second script, one file name was stored in $file just in one loop, and there were more than one loop. What is exactly the difference between these two scripts?

Thanks very much, maybe my question is a little bit naive..

Comment: Note, you should quote `"$file"` when you use it (to protect its whitespace). Had you done that, you might have figured out what's happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior is correct and "as expected".

`for file in $InputDir'*'` means `assign "/home/XXX/*" to $file` (note the quotes). Since you quoted the asterisk, it will not be executed at this time. When the shell sees `echo $file`, it first expands the variables and then it does glob expansion. So after the first step, it sees

```
echo /home/XXX/*
```

and after glob expansion, it sees:

```
echo /home/XXX/fileA /home/XXX/fileB
```

Only now, it will execute the command.

In the second case, the pattern `/home/XXX/*` is expanded before the `for` is executed and thus, each file in the directory is assigned to `file` and then the body of the loop is executed.

This will work:

```
for file in "$InputDir"*
```

but it's brittle; it will fail, for example, when you forget to add a `/` to the end of the variable `$InputDir`.

```
for file in "$InputDir"/*
```

is a little bit better (Unix will ignore double slashes in a path) but it can cause trouble when `$InputDir` is not set or empty: You'll suddenly list files in the `/` (root) folder. This can happen, for example, because of a typo:

```
inputDir=...
for file in "$InputDir"/*
```

Case matters on Unix :-)

To help you understand code like this, use `set -x` ("enable tracing") in a line before the code you want to debug.

Comment: +1 for giving the right explanation. I was typing it, but you were the fastest ^^

Comment: about the "`for file in "$InputDir"*` : (...) it will fail, for example, when you forget to add a `/`"  : you can usually still put the slash: `for file in "$InputDir"/*`  : even if you did put a "/" at the end of InputDir value, it will still be correct on most (all?) systems as /path/to//this  should be pointing to /path/to/this (at least it does on linux, and most Unixes I know about)

Comment: now for the "it can cause trouble when $InputDir is empty": what about :  `for file in "${InputDir:-ERROR__EMPTY_VARIABLE_InputDir}/*"` ? ^^  It's always good to ensure the command won't run on the wrong directory/file. Better to have it try to delete/move/gzip a non-existing one than the whole root ^^

Answer (score 6):

The difference is the quoting of `'*'`. In the first case the loop only executes once, with `$file` equal to `/home/XXX/*` which then expands to all the files in the directory when passed to `echo`. In the second case it executes once per file, with `$file` equal to each file name in turn.

Bottom line - change:

```
for file in $InputDir'*'
```

to:

```
for file in $InputDir*
```

or, better, and to make it more readable - change:

```
InputDir=/home/XXX/
for file in $InputDir'*'
```

to:

```
InputDir=/home/XXX
for file in $InputDir/*
```

Comment: wrong: in the first case, `file` doesn't contain all the files in the directory : it contains `/home/XXX/*`, ie a single value. It is in the `echo $file`  that the * gets interpreted.